# Full screen mode for non-UWP app heads in Uno Platform

Tags: fullscreen, uno-platform

How does/will Uno handle the concept of Full-screen mode in Non-UWP apps?  Will they start up in "Full screen" mode? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

By default WASM and macOS Uno Platform apps will start in Windowed mode and Android and iOS Uno Platform apps start full screen, but with system UI like status bars, navigation bars visible.

On Android and iOS, Uno Platform supports the `ApplicationView.TryEnterFullScreenMode` and `ApplicationView.ExitFullScreenMode` APIs, which make the app "fullscreen" - hiding navigation, status bar, etc. On WASM, full screen mode is not supported at the moment, but I have [filed an issue here on GitHub](https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/issues/2526) to add support for it using the [JavaScript Fullscreen API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API) and will look at it ASAP.

### Update

The Pull Request for this feature is live - https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/pull/2528

I have also done my first live coding session with this feature  - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cZM80_nqoN8